# Accessing NOAA CO-OPS water levels using SOS with bounding box and time extent

Tags: sos

I'm tring to access all water level data within a bounding box and temporal extent using the OGC SOS from the NOAA CO-OPS.  On the page here: http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/ioos-dif-sos/ there is a very useful SOS query builder tool, and I can formulate a query to get all the station data in a specific region:

http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/ioos-dif-sos/SOS?service=SOS&request=GetObservation&version=1.0.0&observedProperty=water_surface_height_above_reference_datum&offering=urn:ioos:network:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:WaterLevelActive&featureOfInterest=BBOX:-74.4751,40.389,-73.7432,40.9397&responseFormat=text%2Fcsv&eventTime=2012-10-26T00:00:00Z/2012-11-01T00:00:00Z&result=VerticalDatum%3D%3Durn:ogc:def:datum:epsg::5103&dataType=VerifiedSixMinute

But when I execute this query it tells me max of 1 day can be requested in a collection.

So I guess there are two approaches.

**Approach 1**: Do a query on collection with bounding box, but only the start time requested:

http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/ioos-dif-sos/SOS?service=SOS&request=GetObservation&version=1.0.0&observedProperty=water_surface_height_above_reference_datum&offering=urn:ioos:network:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:WaterLevelActive&featureOfInterest=BBOX:-74.4751,40.389,-73.7432,40.9397&responseFormat=text%2Fcsv&eventTime=2012-10-26T00:00:00Z&result=VerticalDatum%3D%3Durn:ogc:def:datum:epsg::5103&dataType=VerifiedSixMinute

which returns:

```
station_id,sensor_id,"latitude (degree)","longitude (degree)",date_time,"water_surface_height_above_reference_datum (m)",datum_id,"vertical_position (m)"
urn:ioos:station:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:8518750,urn:ioos:sensor:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:8518750:W1,40.7006,-74.0142,2012-10-26T00:00:00Z,0.446,urn:ogc:def:datum:epsg::5103,1.848
urn:ioos:station:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:8531680,urn:ioos:sensor:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:8531680:W1,40.4669,-74.0094,2012-10-26T00:00:00Z,0.319,urn:ogc:def:datum:epsg::5103,1.624
```

and then I could strip out the station_id and use them in single station queries.

**Approach 2**: Issue multiple collection request for periods of one day and then concatenate the responses together.

I guess I would use approach 1 if I had more days than stations, and approach 2 if I had more stations than days.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are valid and your reasoning is correct. This is more relevant when the requests and responses are handled manually.

If you were to write a small program to do that on your behalf, then that process becomes a breeze.  Here is a link where you can find some sample Java programs that show how you can access data from multiple stations for longer periods of time:

http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/ioos-dif-sos/ClientGetter?p=15

On the other hand issuing a GetCapabilities request before asking for the data of interest will allow you to filter and choose the stations based on their data offerings and their locations.